# XML export in Shopware doesn't finish

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a problem with the XML export function in Shopware 6.4.10.1.

I want to export products but the process is stuck at writing an `.xml.partial` file. The Header and the footer are both missing. When I open the export URL in my browser I can see the complete file, though.

Interestingly, the XML file gets finalized at the very moment I open the URL in my browser. The same happens when I download the XML file with `wget`. So somehow a download triggers something that finalizes the file.

I use the default template provided by Shopware, so no customizations here.

Any advice?

Thanks,
Yutani

Answer (score 0):

There is a task that will write product exports in a set interval. The task will write complete exports including header and footer. However you can set the strategy for product exports to "live". If that is the case only a partial export is generated and the header and footer will be added at runtime. See the [`ProductExportGenerator`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/3efe8d4c9a1284c50798caac0d23579ccc74161d/src/Core/Content/ProductExport/Service/ProductExportGenerator.php#L209) for when header and footer are added and the [`ExportController`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/acfa54681b248e9190d096db6edaeac95adaa4a3/src/Core/Content/ProductExport/SalesChannel/ExportController.php#L125) where it's called if the interval for the export is `0` (a.k.a. "live" strategy).